# Is the compiler of Java Bootstrapped?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, javac, bootstrapping

Is the compiler of Java Bootstrapped ?

How was the first compiler of java written if it is bootstrapped ?

Comment: Please define "bootstrapped".

Comment: @ Paul _that proceeds without external help_

Comment: 'Please explain' what? Compilers are almost always bootstrapped. If you don't know what that means you're not likely to understand that the Java compiler is bootstrapped too.

Comment: @EJP that is not necessarily true.  Java compiler jikes, for example, is written (or at least was when I last checked) in C .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's an interesting question. The current `javac` compiler from Oracle, which is only *one* compiler of many <sup>(1)</sup>, is actually written in Java which means, yes, you could consider it bootstrapped, assuming your definition means "*has* been bootstrapped so that it can now compile itself" <sup>(2)</sup>.

The virtual machine itself is written mostly in C++ from memory so, while the compiler is bootstrapped, building the JRE requires a C++ compiler.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> GCJ is another one, and it happens to be written in C, so it depends on *which* compiler you're referring to.

<sup>(2)</sup> The single word "bootstapped" in your question could be taken in a number of ways. If your definition of "bootstrapped" means "has to *be* bootstrapped to get a working compiler", then the answer is no.

---

As to how the first Java compiler was written before bootstrapping, that remains lost in the mists of time (or the minds of Gosling et al).

Given that a compiler can be written relatively easily without any of the fancy OO concepts, my *guess* would be that they simply wrote the first one (or few) in C or C++.

That seems borne out by [this entry from the Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20010610045734/http://java.sun.com/nav/whatis/storyofjava.html):

> The team's efforts kicked off the development of a new object-oriented programming language that Gosling called Oak, after the tree outside his window. Loosely based on C++, the language was stripped down to a bare minimum in order to be compatible with the limited space the chips in handheld devices would offer, and was designed to allow programmers to more easily support dynamic, changeable hardware.

and, later:

> Arthur van Hoff wrote an Oak compiler entirely in Oak instead of in C. Naughton and Jonathan Payne built an Oak-ready browser called "WebRunner." The first applet -- Duke waving back at his parents over the Internet -- was born.

In addition, from [Patrick Naughton's epilogue](http://www.blinkenlights.com/classiccmp/javaorigin.html) in his book "The java Handbook" (my bold):

> Now that we had a plan of record, to ship Oak in source form on the net, things got much more productive. We started focusing on fixing all of the loose ends in the language. Jonathan Payne was working on optimizing the interpreter. **Arthur van Hoff rewrote the compiler in Oak itself, replacing the C version that James originally wrote.** This was also a good test of the environment since this compiler was the largest single Oak program ever written. A fair number of burned out engineers were using this time as paid vacation by Sun, but for the most part the core team ignored them and got back to work.

So, it looks like the original version of the "Java" (Oak) compiler was written in C, then bootstrapped from there.

Comment: The JDK classes are almost entirely written in Java.

Comment: downvote for terrifying claim that JDK libraries are written in C++.

Comment: Crikes, I can't believe I wrote that. I meant the _JVM!_ Guess I shouldn't answer questions in the middle of a discussion :-)

Comment: _"... the JRE requires a C++ compiler."_ Sure ?

Comment: @grassPro: yes: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/hotspot/hotspot/file/9b0ca45cd756/src/cpu/x86/vm/

Comment: @paxdiablo That's the JVM. Can we please be precise about these terms.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://openjdk.java.net/groups/compiler/:

> Note that the code for the native launcher for javac is shared with
>   all the other JDK tools, and lives in the JDK repository. If you just
>   download and build the langtools repository, you will get an
>   executable jar file which you can invoke directly with the java
>   command, or with a simple shell script that is provided.

Therefore the compiler is written in Java.  So yes, it is bootstrapped in the sense that you need to compile it with an earlier version of the Java compiler.

Comment: Isn't that a chicken and egg problem? How did they write the first Java compiler if it needed Java to compile to Java which requires Java to compile to Java...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(compilers)#The_chicken_and_egg_problem